# ARC forbids Objective-C objects in structs or unions despite marking the file -fno-objc-arc

Tags: iphone, objective-c, struct, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

ARC forbids Objective-C objects in structs or unions despite marking the file -fno-objc-arc?
Why is this so?

I had the assumption that if you mark it -fno-objc-arc you don't have this restriction.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

If you got this message try __unsafe_unretained. It is only safe, if the objects in the struct are unretained. 
Example: If you use OpenFeint with ARC the Class OFBragDelegateStrings says this error in a struct.

```
typedef struct OFBragDelegateStrings
{
     NSString* prepopulatedText;
     NSString* originalMessage;
} OFBragDelegateStrings;
```

to

```
typedef struct OFBragDelegateStrings
{
     __unsafe_unretained NSString* prepopulatedText;
     __unsafe_unretained NSString* originalMessage;
} OFBragDelegateStrings;
```

Comment: it also creating problems when i allocate the string it shows warning 
assigning retained object to unsafe_unretained variable object will be released after assignment. And when i use  it crashes

Comment: This doesn't solve all problems, the object would normally be immediately released and thus unavailable.

Comment: yes--this doesn't actually work... the solution is to somehow turn off ARC for a derived source file which I haven't been able to figure out yet...

Comment: You do that by adding the -fno-objc-arc flag to the file in the build phase.

Comment: What if the struct field is only a "dumb reference", and the object is actually being retained (owned) somewhere else (say, inside an `NSArray`)? In that case, it won't be immediately deallocated, but I wonder what the compiler will say (can't test it right now)...

Answer (score 30):

**Rather** than using a **struct**, you can create an **Objective-C class** to manage the data instead.

Comment: how? where is the sample?

Comment: So why can't struct for small use cases?

Answer (score 13):

That is because arc can't track objects in structs or unions (since they are at that point plain C pointers).

Even though you marked the file/class in question with  `-fno-objc-arc` you might still pass an object controlled by arc to it as parameter, which would most likely result in a memory leak.

Comment: But then how I am able to use arc and non-arc files in my projects. For example I use sharekit as non-arc and I am able to use instances to publish. The files I am using it are arc files.

Comment: You can use `-fno-objc-arc` to mix ARC and non ARC files within a project, but if you're using plain C structures like struct or union anywhere you can't use ARC at all.

Comment: Thanks voidStern.. "but if you're using plain C structures like struct or union anywhere you can't use ARC at all." - I don't think this is true. I am using ARC for my own files. And non-arc for the libharu files. The way I went around my original problem was to pass in the values separately to the C file and create the struct there. I think the key is the jump from arc to non-arc to arc.

Comment: At all might be a little exaggerated. In essence you can't put pointers to objects into structs and unions, which would confuse ARC. Using a plain C library with structs and/or unions should (usually) be possible.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like this now works without errors, probably after [this change](https://reviews.llvm.org/D41228).

i.e., You can put normal (strong) pointers to Objective-C objects in a C struct. It is managed by ARC e.g., it is unretained when the struct is destructed. Verified with:

`$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.2)`

Comment: [What's New in LLVM](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/409/?time=218) - WWDC 2018