# Remembering performSelector: for later in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, callback, box2d

In the box2d physics loop of my game (the step), I must call the following block:

```
if ([objectA conformsToProtocol:@protocol(FMCollisionProtocol)]) {
    [objectA performSelector:@selector(collideWith:) withObject:objectB];
}
if ([objectB conformsToProtocol:@protocol(FMCollisionProtocol)]) {
    [objectB performSelector:@selector(collideWith:) withObject:objectA];
}
```

The problem is that `collideWith:` may alter my physics object and this isn't allowed during the step. Once the step is finished, the physics objects are free to be altered once more. I need some way to remember the target, selector and object paramater of this block for later use. One option would be to use a struct like this:

```
typedef struct {
    id target;
    SEL selector;
    id object;
} FMCallback;
```

And store these in an array. Once I've finished my step, I then analyse this array and call `performSelector:`. Is there a better way around this?

**EDIT:**

I tried both ways and found blocks to be simpler. I'm using a protocol, so I was unsure how to handle this (it would always return a nil NSMethodSignature):

```
NSMethodSignature *sig = [FMObject instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:@selector(collideWith:)];
NSInvocation *invoc = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];
invoc.target = objectB;
invoc.selector = @selector(collideWith:);
[invoc setArgument:objectA atIndex:2];
[Presenter.physics.callbacks addObject:invoc];
```

It was also longer than I would have hoped. The blocks worked fine after some reading:

```
// In the collision
[Presenter.physics.callbacks addObject: Block_copy(^{
    [(id)objectB collideWith:objectA];
})];

// After the step
for (id collision in callbacks_) {
    ((dispatch_block_t)collision)();
    Block_release(collision);
}
[callbacks_ removeAllObjects];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about blocks?

```
NSMutableArray *collisions = [NSMutableArray array];
…
[collisions addObject:^{
    [objectA collideWith:objectB];
}];
…
for (id collision in collisions)
    ((dispatch_block_t)collision)();
```

This is with ARC; without ARC you should probably add a `copy` and `autorelease` when adding the blocks to the array.

Comment: Closures are a welcome addition to any language, I am glad we have them in Objective-C now. In other words, do read the docs, as blocks solve a lot of day-to-day situations in a nice way.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps an `NSInvocation`?

---

Comment: Nice to know they've already made an object to pass callbacks with :) The struct would probably be faster but I doubt it would matter much

Comment: One benefit is that it's an object, so I can use NSArray, rather than a C array.

Comment: @AramKocharyan Plus you may have issues with struct if you switch to ARC.

Comment: Cheers for the warning http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093099/arc-forbids-objective-c-objects-in-structs-or-unions-despite-marking-the-file-f

Comment: well, you'd be going through a whole alloc and free, plus several ref count ops (and so on) -- a struct would certainly be *faster*. perhaps you can reuse the invocation, if that really is a concern in your case.

Comment: I tried to use NSInvocation but went with blocks instead. See my update. Thanks for pointing me in their direction though.

Comment: @Aram - well, you could wrap up that boilerplate invocation code to a one-liner. at any rate, glad you found a good answer.

Comment: Cheers, I thought of making a category for that