# Converting to ARC doesn't recognize -fno-objc-arc flag

Tags: ios, ios5

I am finally trying to convert my ios project to ARC. there is several files that I do not want to convert to ARC, so I have added the "-fno-objc-arc" flag to build phase -> compile sources to the corresponding *.m file.

However, when I try to edit -> refactor -> convert to ARC, I am getting a "Cannot Convert to Objective-C ARC: Xcode found 3 issues that prevent conversion from proceeding.  Fix all ARC readiness issues and try again." error

the errors are all on the *.h file for which I have added the -fno-objc-arc to for the corresponding *.m file... Do I have to add the flag to the *.h file too? If so, where can I find it?

Thanks!

**EDIT** So I read the error more clearly. the file i am having issue with is JSONKit.h. The errors are not generated in JSONKit.m, but other classes that I wrote which imports JSONKit.h  So is the only solution to add the -fno-objc-arc flag to my own classes that imports JSONKit.h? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a design error on your side. Could you post one of the errors and the corresponding header entry?

Comment: It seems like you are mixing metaphors by adding he -fno... flag before converting to ARC. If you have files you want to keep "normal", why not remove them from your target, refactor, then add them back and add the flag?

Comment: hi I made an edit. the line of code highlighted for ARC Restrictions error is simply "#import "JSONKit.h"".  The same line on JSONKit.m does not have this error since I added the -fno-objc-arc to JSONKit.m. So must I add the flag to the classes I created which import JSONKit.h? I might have more classes in the future that relies on JSONKit; that would not be ideal... thx

Comment: Thanks David, I do want to convert all my self-written classes to ARC, just that some of them (and more in the future probably) imports JSONKit.h which is not ARC compliant and I do not want to mess with JSONKit myself...

Comment: I used that JSONKit myself in an all ARC project. I think I had converted to ARC before adding it, and when I added it it was the ONLY file I had to use the -fno flag with. I think my suggestion will work for you.

Comment: I tried doing similar just now. I removed all the import JSONKit.h lines, refactor to ARC successfully. then added the import JSONKit.h line again (I do have the -fno flag for JSONKit.m in my compile sources). However, when I try to build my project, I get the exact same error as before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

temporary getaround (unless someone can suggest better)

I have having error with the following in JSONKit.h

```
typedef struct {
   JKParseOptionFlags  parseOptionFlags;
   JKConstBuffer       stringBuffer;
   size_t              atIndex, lineNumber, lineStartIndex;
   size_t              prev_atIndex, prev_lineNumber, prev_lineStartIndex;
   int                 errorIsPrev;
   JKParseToken        token;
   JKObjectStack       objectStack;
   JKTokenCache        cache;
   JKObjCImpCache      objCImpCache;
   NSError            *error;
 } JKParseState;
```

the error is on the NSError line - "ARC forbids Objective-C objects in structs or unions"

following [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093099/arc-forbids-objective-c-objects-in-structs-or-unions-despite-marking-the-file-f), I changed the line to

> __unsafe_unretained NSError *error;

and it compiles... seems to work ok so far