# how to use __unsafe_unretained in Structure

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am converting my project to ARC
I am using structure in my project.
 
It is giving me error while converting into ARC

```
ARC forbids Objective-C objects in structs or unionsrk - type definition for struct
```

I search in SO and I found out that using `__unsafe_unretained`.It will solve the issue. So I used it in my sturcture.

```
typedef struct Grade{
  __unsafe_unretained NSString  *Table,
                                *RowId,
                                *ScheduleID,
                                *Level,
                                *Label,
                                *Thershold;

    char *CreateStmt;
} grade;
```

It is working but now it is showing the same error in next line at `*RowId`.
 My question is Should I put the __unsafe_unretained before all the variable. Is It safe to do that? or there is another way to fix this.

Comment: See this stackoverflow.com/questions/8093099/arc-forbids-objective-c-objects-in-structs-or-unions-despite-marking-the-file-f

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093099/arc-forbids-objective-c-objects-in-structs-or-unions-despite-marking-the-file-f

Comment: I am putting in that way. but my question is . is it safe that use like this. like put  __unsafe_unretained before all the variable?

Comment: it is `__unsafe_unretained` so what do you think it is safe or not? you have to make sure the references in the struct will be cleared after when they are released. anyway, why not create a class for that?

Comment: ok thanks @xls. There are more than one struct in that class so i dont have to create individual class. and it has  only NSString and char type object in the structure . so I create struct instead of class.

Comment: You should make it a class.

Comment: But what is the issue with struct @nielsbol. can you explain?

Comment: See [Common Issues While Converting a Project](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW16) in the "Transitioning to ARC Release Notes": *"This is because x defaults to strongly retained and the compiler can’t safely synthesize all the code required to make it work correctly. ..."* The recommended solution is to replace the struct by an Objective-C object.

Answer (score 2):

ARC can not work with object in structs, there is a technical reason for it but I always forget it, you can disable ARC for the those element in a struct using the __unsafe_unretained modifier but then you have no memory management whats so every, even your own. There are some private functions to retain and release object but they are private so you can't depend on them, you may run into trouble with apples app store. The best way to handle this is to turn of ARC for the .m files that have structs with object elements, (use -fno-objc-arc on those files) and then do all of the memory management manually for everything in that file. You could use categories to reduce the amount of code that is needed to do manually reference counting, you can have ARC off for the class file and then ARC on for one of its categories for example.

Comment: The technical reason is documented in [Common Issues While Converting a Project](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW16) in the "Transitioning to ARC Release Notes": *"This is because x defaults to strongly retained and the compiler can’t safely synthesize all the code required to make it work correctly. ..."* The recommended solution is to replace the struct by an Objective-C object.