# Problems with ARC on xcode 5 and mavericks

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

That's the problem, when I try to build my xcproject xcode show me an error on the 3rd row of the following code :

```
typedef struct 
{
    NSArray *array;
    NSString *string;
}WYnot;
```

the error is: " ARC forbids Objective-C objects in struct ".

How can I solve this problem??? Is it actual an error or not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093099/arc-forbids-objective-c-objects-in-structs-or-unions-despite-marking-the-file-f

Comment: Have a look at "ARC Enforces New Rules" in the [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had simmilar issue and I sorted it by added `__unsafe_unretained` keyword like that:

```
typedef struct 
{
    __unsafe_unretained NSArray *array;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *string;
}WYnot;
```

Try it should help.

Comment: Yes, that is one answer to the "possible duplicate" (see @gtgaxiola's comment above).

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct
{
    CFArrayRef array;
    CFStringRef string;
}WYnot;
```

This works. I assume that You have some misunderstanding that struct is a part of C not of objectiveC.

Comment: `CFArrayRef` and `NSArray *` are not the same with regard to ARC. So this does not answer the question.

Comment: Ok. Agreed. Proper answer will be: Use only C structs when create C struct.

Comment: So I can't create a struct with an NSArray?

Comment: Yep. At glanse You can convert CFArrays to NSArrays but there are not same things for compiler.